# Pycharm cant install Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, pycharm

i have been following for a tutorial for learning the Django rest framework and have been using pycharm to do it.

Typically when i do pip install  and install it in the package modules in the settings, the red squiggly lines go away and the package is installed.

I have also tried alt+enter with the cursor over the package but not luck with that either.

I have tried using conda as well but i end up getting the same result:
conda install -c conda-forge djangorestframework

I would normally ignore the red squiggles but i have found that since it doesnt recognize that the package is installed, i cant use it when i run the shell and try to test stuff out using rest_framework. thus it throws an error.

These are the packages i have installed through pip:

```
django-filter==2.0.0
django-rest-framework==0.1.0
djangorestframework==3.8.2
idna==2.7
Markdown==2.6.11
Pillow==5.2.0
pytz==2018.5
requests==2.19.1
urllib3==1.23
```

i am running pycharm version:
[image]

I cant figure out why the rest_framework module cant be installed into pycharm. This is the error its giving me:

[image]

Does anyone know how to resolve this or perhaps know where start?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: install drf( using pip and import project in pycharm and configure setting like virtual enve project interpreter,etc

Comment: i've never heard of drf but ill start looking it up and let you know how it goes.

Comment: check http://www.django-rest-framework.org/#installation

Comment: Are you using virtual_envirnment ?

Comment: @JerinPeterGeorge yes, if you look below the error, you'll see im in (restapi)

Comment: @HemanthSP I was not thinking clearly last night and didnt connect the dots that drf = djangorestframework. i already have it installed by using pip which i have listed in my question. The configuration setting in pycharm does not have it as an option to install. i will update my question to show.

Answer (score 1):

All, I have figured it out. I was using a very old virtual environment with a slew of packages IN PYCHARM in which installing DRF was not an option for some reason. It wasnt until i created a new and fresh virtual environment in pycharm that i had the option for installing the DRF packages. A bit odd.

If anyone knows why this is, please comment below, otherwise problem solved and thank you for all your efforts.